# Calling eddyhub.gnome_shell role (from ansible galaxy) from another role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to install gnome extensions in an ansible playbook and found this: https://galaxy.ansible.com/eddyhub/gnome_shell/ nice!

The way I am organzing my playbook, I would like to call the role from within another task, so I created a task like this (this is the complete task file, located at (roles/common/tasks/gnome.yaml):

```
dependencies:
   - { role: eddyhub.gnome_shell, gnome_extension_path: /home/nathanhuesken/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/, gnome_extension_owner: nathanhuesken, gnome_shell_extensions: [442] }
```

But running the playbook, I get this error:

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: global name 'AnsibleError' is not defined
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 92, in <module>
    exit_code = cli.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 154, in run
    results = pbex.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 73, in run
    pb = Playbook.load(playbook_path, variable_manager=self._variable_manager, loader=self._loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 53, in load
    pb._load_playbook_data(file_name=file_name, variable_manager=variable_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 98, in _load_playbook_data
    entry_obj = Play.load(entry, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=self._loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 115, in load
    return p.load_data(data, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 206, in load_data
    self._attributes[name] = method(name, ds[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 217, in _load_roles
    roles.append(Role.load(ri, play=self))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/role/__init__.py", line 116, in load
    r._load_role_data(role_include, parent_role=parent_role)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/role/__init__.py", line 169, in _load_role_data
    self._task_blocks = load_list_of_blocks(task_data, play=self._play, role=self, loader=self._loader, variable_manager=self._variable_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/helpers.py", line 58, in load_list_of_blocks
    loader=loader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/block.py", line 79, in load
    return b.load_data(data, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 206, in load_data
    self._attributes[name] = method(name, ds[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/block.py", line 115, in _load_block
    use_handlers=self._use_handlers,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/helpers.py", line 178, in load_list_of_tasks
    raise AnsibleError("included task files must contain a list of tasks", obj=data)
NameError: global name 'AnsibleError' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **included task files must contain a list of tasks** – you include files in the wrong way. Please provide playbook snippets with `include` statements and files you try to include.

Comment: I do not have any playbook snippets with include statements in my playbook

Comment: Where did you type `dependencies:`? Please post the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are putting a clause `dependencies:` (which is not an Ansible module) into the task file, while it belongs to the `meta/main.yml` (read more about [role dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies)).

Currently there is no way of calling a role from the task in Ansible.